WhatsApp hyperlink not working as expected
I am using the "https://wa.me/1XXXXXXXXXX" on my footer WhatsApp icon. But clicking the link, takes me to the "This link is incorrect. Close this window and try a different link.
" page.
Can anyone please help to overcome this issue?
I checked WhatsApp's guidance on this: https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934. I am facing the same issue on the web and mobile.

Thank you to everyone who replied, but I figured out the solution myself. Since it's a WordPress site using Elementor, all I had to do was put the mobile number in the URL field, and it worked.

Add this simple HTML to your website:
1. With WhatsApp Logo:
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=123456789000&text=Hi+%21+how+can+I+help+you%3F&type=phone_number&app_absent=0" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/MoFGGKV.png" alt="Whatsapp Link" style="width:42px;height:42px;"></a>
2. With WhatsApp Text
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=123456789000&text=Hi+%21+how+can+I+help+you%3F&type=phone_number&app_absent=0" target="_blank">Whatsapp</a>
Do not use + before your number. Just start with your country code and replace your business number with 123456789000.
